# Attempt to split string on '//' in Jenkinsfile splits on '/' instead

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

> **What is the correct way to tokenize a string on double-forward-slash `//` in a `Jenkinsfile`?**

The example below results in the string being tokenized on single-forward-slash `/` instead, which is not the desired behavior.

---

**Jenkinsfile**

---

An abbreviated, over-simplified example of the `Jenkinsfile` containing the relevant part is:

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()

    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            def theURL = "http://<ip-on-lan>:<port-num>/path/to/some.asset"
            sh "echo 'theURL is: ${theURL}'"
            def tokenizedURL = theURL.tokenize('//')
            sh "echo 'tokenizedURL is: ${tokenizedURL}'"
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

---

**The Logs:**

---

The log output from the preceding is:

```
echo 'theURL is: http://<ip-on-lan>:<port-num>/path/to/some.asset'— Shell Script<1s
    [ne_Branch-Name-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    + echo theURL is: http://<ip-on-lan>:<port-num>/path/to/some.asset
    theURL is: http://<ip-on-lan>:<port-num>/path/to/some.asset

echo 'tokenizedURL is: [http:, <ip-on-lan>:<port-num>, path, to, some.asset]'— Shell Script<1s  
    [ne_Branch-Name-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    + echo tokenizedURL is: [http:, <ip-on-lan>:<port-num>, path, to, some.asset]
    tokenizedURL is: [http:, <ip-on-lan>:<port-num>, path, to, some.asset]
```

**Note that the logs show that the string is being tokeni on `/` instead of on `//`.**

Comment: What about using some Groovy/Java library that actually understands the syntax of a URI? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tokenize` takes string as optional argument](http://grails.asia/groovy-tokenize) that may contain 1 or more characters as delimiters. It treats each character in string argument as separate delimiter so `//` **is effectively** same as `/`

To split on `//`, you may use `split` that supports regex:

```
theURL.split(/\/{2}/)
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/6SJ4Ry)